# How would I go about categorizing items within an Array in swift?

Tags: arrays, xcode, string, swift, sorting

In swift, I want to categorize items in an existing array and place them accordingly in one new string.

Here is an example of what I want to do:

```
originalArray = ["hotdog","fries","hotdog","coke","coke","fries","hotdog"]

resultingString = "hotdog x 3, fries x 2, coke x 2"
```

How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
let originalArray = ["hotdog","fries","hotdog","coke","coke","fries","hotdog"]
var dict = [String: Int]()

let resultString = originalArray.reduce(dict) { _, element in
    if dict[element] == nil {
        dict[element] = 1
    } else {
        dict[element]! += 1
    }
    return dict
}
.map { "\($0) x \($1)" }
.joinWithSeparator(", ")
```

If you want to keep the original order of the array (ie: hotdog, fries, coke), the code is slightly more complicated:

```
let originalArray = ["hotdog","fries","hotdog","coke","coke","fries","hotdog"]
var dict = [String: (index: Int, count: Int)]()

let resultString = originalArray.enumerate()
    .reduce(dict) { _ , e in
        if let value = dict[e.element] {
            dict[e.element] = (index: value.index, count: value.count + 1)
        } else {
            dict[e.element] = (index: e.index, count: 1)
        }
        return dict
    }
    .sort { return $0.1.index < $1.1.index }
    .map { "\($0) x \($1.count)" }
    .joinWithSeparator(", ")

print(resultString)
```

Comment: It works, but with one catch: when i print resultString i get "hotdog x 3, fries x 2, coke x 2\n" how do i get rid of "/n"?

Comment: The \n is only visible in playground. It will disappear inside a real project

Comment: O you're right, it ended up working in my project. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 2):

I think this will help you:

```
let originalArray = ["hotdog","fries","hotdog","coke","coke","fries","hotdog"]
var resultingString = ""
var counts:[String:Int] = [:]
for item in originalArray {
    counts[item] = (counts[item] ?? 0) + 1

}
resultingString = counts.map { (key, value) -> String in
    return "\(key) x \(value)"
}.joinWithSeparator(",")

print(resultingString)
```

Here is the output: `coke x 2, hotdog x 3, fries x 2`

Comment: your code also works, but with one catch: it also returns "hotdog x 3, fries x 2, coke x 2\n" when i print resultingString, how do i get rid of "/n"?

Comment: print(resultingString, terminator:"")

Comment: Yes that seems to work, thanks so much for your help!